# Cómo coger últimas filas de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Estoy actualizando una tabla en función de cuando una tenga nuevos registros. Ya tengo el nº de nuevos registros. El problema es que no tengo ni idea de con qué consulta en SQL puedo coger, por ejemplo, los cinco últimos registros de la tabla (para luego insertarlos en la otra tabla). Lo haría con PHP, no sé si debería guardar los registros en un array o algo y luego recorrerlos para hacer el insert en la otra tabla. Muchas gracias, saludos.

```
for ($i=$punto_corte_actualizar; $i <$total_registros_MSAccess ; $i++) { //Este bucle me recorre desde el punto de corte para actualizar hasta el final de la tabla  
            
                $query="SELECT Marketplace, IdPedido, fecha, [nombre cliente] AS nombre, direccion, DNI, cp, poblacion, provincia, Estado FROM pedidos ASC";
                $rs_registros_MS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $query);
                $pedidos_MS_actualizar=odbc_fetch_array($rs_registros_MS);
```

Este es el código que estoy haciendo, pero me da error de sintaxis en la cláusula FROM, pero no comprendo por qué.

P.D. Ahora mismo los registros los quiero coger de una tabla de MS Access y luego insertarlos en una tabla MySQL, supongo que influye en el código.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 5 tabla.* FROM tabla ORDER BY id DESC;`, ¿cómo estás accediendo a MS Access y MySQL? Modifica tu preguntar aportando tu código y podremos ayudarte un poco más

Comment: ¿La base de datos es MySQL o MS Access? La consulta variará en este caso, por lo que debes indicar claramente que SGBD estás usando.

Comment: @A.Cedano el OP indica que lee de MS Access y escribe en MySQL :)

Comment: @DavidJP ok. Lo que creo es que quiere pasar datos de una BD (Access) a otra (MySQL). En ese caso, tendría que hacer dos conexiones: una a Access para ejecutar el `SELECT` y otra a MySQL para ejecutar el INSERT. El error de sintaxis puede ser porque está conectado a MySQL, el cual no admite esto `[columna con espacio]`, en MySQL hay que usar backticks.

Comment: De momento está leyendo por ODBC, después entiendo que, efectivamente, se conectará por `mysqli` para el `INSERT`

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta el `ORDER BY` y el campo por el que quieres ordenar antes del ASC. Prueba así:

```
SELECT Marketplace, IdPedido, fecha,
  [nombre cliente] AS nombre, direccion, DNI, cp, 
  poblacion, provincia, Estado 
  FROM pedidos
  WHERE fecha>#2020-10-08 14:38:05#
  ORDER BY IdPedido DESC;
```

Comment: El ORDER BY no es por ningún campo, si no por los últimos 5 de la tabla. El orden me da igual.

Comment: @Sergio, si ordenas, tiene que ser por algún campo. Si quieres obtener los 5 últimos últimos eso implica un orden, y un  buen campo es el `IdPedido`

Comment: De acuerdo. A ver, dudas:

-El top nº, ese nº de registros es variable, según los nº que haya que insertar de una tabla a otra (que varía según la diferencia en el nº de registros que haya desde la última actualización). ¿Cómo se lo puedo indicar?

-Con el código actual, me saca el mismo registro dos veces.

Comment: Ah, entonces no necesitas los últimos 5 registros, sino los nuevos desde la última actualización. Para ello, tendrías que consultar en MySQL cuándo realizaste la última inserción y leer en MS Access todos los registros desde esa fecha. Te amplío la respuesta